# Devise returns invalid email or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating a user through the console successfully.
Then I am trying to login and I am getting an invalid email or password error.
Here is my view

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), id: 'loginForm') do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :Username %><br />
                  <%= f.text_field :email, autofocusout: true, placeholder:"example@gmail.com", title:"Please enter you username", required: "", value:"", class:"form-control" %>
                  <span class="help-block small">Your unique username to app</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :password %><br />
                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", type:"password", title:"Please enter your password", placeholder:"******", required:"", value:"", name:"password", id:"password", class:"form-control" %>
                  <span class="help-block small">Your strong password</span>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "i-checks", checked:"checked"  %>
                  <%= f.label :remember_login %>
                    <p class="help-block small">(if this is a private computer)</p>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Login", class:"btn btn-success btn-block" %>
                <%= link_to "forgotten password?", new_password_reset_path %>
              <% end %>

Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-24 04:33:36 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"BESzQQh1yIuyQo8YIp4qh5IVqUXif0B/LyPeeGzdlZc=", "user"=>{"email"=>"tst@gmail.com", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Comment: Post your controller please. What have you written to create a user?

Comment: Look at the logs in your rails server and post it please

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.